# Laravel 5.1. Token from and session token are different using mobile browser (login action)

Tags: laravel, authentication, access-token

I have got this login form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    ...
```

I login with no problem using a browser from a desktop (IE, Chrome, Firefox, ...), but the problem comes from mobile device (android platform).

I got this exceptión:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53.
```

When I went to VerifyCsrfToken.php I discovered that the token passed from the form and the token taked from session object are different. But this only happens from my android phone.

On function called `tokensMatch` in the file VerifyCsrfToken.php ([link to github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php)) I add this code to see what was happening:

```
echo '<br>X-CSRF-TOKEN:'.$request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
echo '<br>X-XSRF-TOKEN:'.$request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN');
echo '<br>token:'.$request->input('_token');
echo '<br>sessionToken:'.$request->session()->token();
```

Token and sessionToken are different (the other two value are empty).

Any clues about this? This only happens using a mobile device (two android tested).

**UPDATE**: I set the token input to text to view the content from the browser. The thing is that in mobile devices when I refresh the url [domain.com]/auth/login, the token changes in every call, however, from desktop browser the token do not change. I think that in mobile devices the sessions is created and destroyed in every call.

**UPDATE 2**: I confirm that the problems comes by the changing of token in every request. I don't know that this happens only from mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

The problem was a wrong value of 'domain' key in session.php. On mobile devices for any reason the cookies policies are more restricted.

I had got this value:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'www.[mydomain].com'),
```

I need to remove `www.`, so this value must be like this:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '[mydomain].com'),
```

For any reason from desktop browser with no special configuration the cookie works with no problem.