# Laravel 5.1. Session token changes in each request only from mobile devices

Tags: laravel, session, token

I've discovered a strange thing in my Laravel 5.1.28 web page. The session token changes in every request when I use a mobile device (android, iphone). I see this in two places.

One, on the development bar on the session tab. 
Two, when I write in the view `{{ csrf_token() }}` (For example, I put `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in a login form and the _token changes in very reload.

This breaks my login form and I can't login from any mobile device (tested in moto 2 gen and on iphone 6). However, I've said, the token works well from desktop (firefox, chrome, ie) and from tablets (ipad).

Any clues about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118406/laravel-5-1-token-from-and-session-token-are-different-using-mobile-browser-lo), admin could think that this is the same question)

Solved.

The problem was a wrong value of 'domain' key in session.php. On mobile devices for any reason the cookies policies are more restricted.

I had got this value:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'www.[mydomain].com'),
```

I need to remove `www.`, so this value must be like this:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '[mydomain].com'),
```

For any reason from desktop browser with no special configuration the cookie works with no problem.